# Floating point accuracy with different languages

Tags: c++, floating-point, language-agnostic, precision, transcendental-equation

I'm currently doing distance calculations between coordinates and have been getting slightly different results depending on the language used.

Part of the calculation is taking calculating the `cosine` of a given `radian`. I get the following results

```
// cos(0.8941658257446736)

// 0.6261694290123146 node
// 0.6261694290123146 rust
// 0.6261694290123148 go
// 0.6261694290123148 python
// 0.6261694290123148 swift
// 0.6261694290123146 c++
// 0.6261694290123146 java
// 0.6261694290123147 c
```

I would like to try and understand why. If you look past `16dp` `c` is the only "correct" answer in terms of rounding. What I am surprised as is `python` having a different result.

This small difference is being amplified currently and over 000's of positions it is adding a not insignificant distance.

Not really sure how this is a duplicate. Also I am more asking for a holistic answer rather than language specific. I don't have a compute science degree.

---

**UPDATE**

I accept that maybe this is too broad a question I suppose I was curious as to why as my background isn't CS. I appreciate the links to the blogs that were posted in the comments.

---

**UPDATE 2**

This question arose from porting a service from `nodejs` to `go`. `Go` is even weirder as I am now unable to run tests as the summation of distances varies with multiple values.

Given a list of coordinates and calculating the distance and adding them together I get different results. I'm not asking a question but seems crazy that `go` will produce different results.

```
9605.795975874069
9605.795975874067
9605.79597587407
```

For completeness here is the Distance calculation I am using:

```golang
func Distance(pointA Coordinate, pointB Coordinate) float64 {
    const R = 6371000 // Earth radius meters
    phi1 := pointA.Lat * math.Pi / 180
    phi2 := pointB.Lat * math.Pi / 180
    lambda1 := pointA.Lon * math.Pi / 180
    lambda2 := pointB.Lon * math.Pi / 180

    deltaPhi := phi2 - phi1
    deltaLambda := lambda2 - lambda1
    a := math.Sin(deltaPhi/2)*math.Sin(deltaPhi/2) + math.Cos(phi1)*math.Cos(phi2)*math.Sin(deltaLambda/2)*math.Sin(deltaLambda/2)
    c := 2 * math.Atan2(math.Sqrt(a), math.Sqrt(1-a))

    d := R * c
    return d
}
```

Comment: The results you posted are the results _somehow_ displayed to you. That _somehow_ might involve rounding and truncating, varies on languages and the way you print it. For example Go's output is `0.6261694290123148`, but if you use "higher precision" printing like `fmt.Printf("%.25f", v)`, you'll get `0.6261694290123147599302911`. The 16th fraction digit becomes `7` not `8` compared to when printed using the default format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [double and accuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11110130/double-and-accuracy)   You are right on the edge and this will depend on how `cos` is implemented and if 80-bit floating point is used for the intermediate results.

Comment: Basically you are asking 10 questions in one (like "what does X do in language Y", for 10 different languages). Plus: telling us what you think your code does ... isnt sufficient. See [mcve]. How are supposed to tell you what kind of FP problem you might have, without being able to look at the exact code that created one of those lines?!

Comment: Its not that difficult to replicate, simply calculating `cosine`, need the exact syntax for every lanuage?? This is using builtins for every language so dont understand what you would like. Im asking a more holistic question as @icza has done

Comment: Fun fact: In C++ it is very possible that `x = 0.8941658257446736; assert(cos(x) == cos(x + argc/1000));` fires (one might be computed at compile time, the other at run-time, possibly using different methods). See the "Transcendentals" section at https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/07/16/floating-point-determinism/. So yes, the exact syntax (and compiler, and flags, and floating point rounding mode, etc.) used may be relevant.

Comment: If your question is "why does this happen" then I recommend the above blog post (pretty C/C++-specific) as well as [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). It's just way too broad a question to explain in detail why each language does these things as it does, and I'm not sure if a "because floating point math is not usually an exact science" satisfies you. If you have a more specific question, feel free to express it.

Comment: Also read about rounding issues: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/07/16/floating-point-determinism/  And Intermediate Precision https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/03/21/intermediate-floating-point-precision/

Comment: Might also want to look up the "paranoia test" (paranoia.c), which is some old industry standard for determining floating point conformance on different systems.

Comment: Fact remains that you ask 10 questions in 1. That alone renders your question too broad. And yes, sometimes subtle changes MIGHT play out in subtle ways.

Comment: Does “calculations between coordinates” mean you’re calculating the distance between two points on earth?

Comment: The C result is, in my opinion, the only reasonable one there.

Comment: If the problem you are solving is affected by such a small difference in the result of the `cos` calculation, then it also depends just as much on the accuracy of the radian argument to it. It's pretty unlikely you know the argument to the required accuracy. That seems like a more fundamental problem.

Comment: @VGR yeah using a simple havisine calculation based upone spherical earth.

Comment: @GhostCat I respectfully disagree. Given the same input the builtin functions provide different results and dont round how I would have expected. Im asking what is at play that accounts for that. Maybe stackoverflow is the right medium to get an answer to that.

Comment: Is it possible your ‘spherical earth’ assumption is the reason for the “not insignificant distance” discrepancies?

Comment: @VGR the above differences are just from one part of the distance calculation - specifically `cos(radian)`, not the distance its self.

Comment: Although OP says the C result is the only “correct” answer, it is the only one that is impossible for a correctly rounded display of an IEEE-754 binary64 value. The two nearest representable values are 0.62616942901231464890798861233633942902088165283203125 and 0.6261694290123147599302910748519934713840484619140625, for which correctly rounding to 17 digits produces a numeral ending in 6 or 8, not 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the representation of floating point numbers is defined by the standard [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) and my assumption is that this standard is implemented by all (major) programming languages.

Precision and rounding are [known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577179/c-floating-point-precision) and may sometimes [lead to unexpected results](https://floating-point-gui.de/).

Aspects that may have an influence on the result of a calculation depending on the programming language or used math library:

- different calculation methods (in your case: the cosine function
  might be implemented by [numerical approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis) with different approaches)
- different [rounding strategies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Rounding_modes) during calculation or for the final output

Comment: it is not language matter, but hardware (CPU and FPU design).

Comment: @MarekR: Hardware can make IEEE754 easier or harder to implement, but you can do IEEE754 fully in software.

Answer (score 2):

IEEE-754 only requires basic operations (`+-*/`) and `sqrt` to be correctly rounded, i.e. the error must be no more than 0.5ULP. Transcendental functions like `sin`, `cos`, `exp`... are very complex so they're only [recommended to be correctly rounded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Recommended_operations). Different implementations may use different algorithms to calculate the result for those functions depending on the space and time requirements. Therefore variations like you observed is completely normal

> There is no standard that requires faithful rounding of transcendental functions. IEEE-754 (2008) *recommends*, but does not require, that these functions be correctly rounded.
>
> [Standard for the sine of very large numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6665681/995714)

## See also

- [Math precision requirements of C and C++ standard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20945815/995714)
- [If two languages follow IEEE 754, will calculations in both languages result in the same answers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37928129/995714)
- [Does any floating point-intensive code produce bit-exact results in any x86-based architecture?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27149894/995714)

Comment: “Correctly rounded” and “faithfully rounded” are specific terms in floating-point, and they need to be used carefully. “Properly rounded” is not a specifically defined phrase; it would depend on context as to what “proper” is. “Correct” rounding is the strictest: The floating-point result must be the infinitely precise result rounded to the number uniquely determined by the rounding rules. This is not equivalent to rounding of at most ½ ULP, as the rule for ties must be obeyed. “Faithful” is looser: The result may be one of the two immediately surrounding neighbors.

Comment: The phrase “only recommended to be properly rounded” has “only” near “recommended” although it is more likely intended to modify “properly rounded.”

Comment: Also worth noting is that humans do not yet know how to evaluate all the “elementary” functions (sine, cosine, logarithm, and so on) with correct rounding in a known-bounded execution time. Nobody would be able to implement a library satisfying IEEE 754’s recommendation with a known bound on execution time without new research. At my suggestion, the committee voted to recommend faithful rounding, but it was changed in balloting after the committee finished its work.